# What is the scope of console when working with modules?

Tags: javascript, scope, console, global-scope

I have just learned about modules in javascript
Until now I have run my code all in one file, so all top level variables in the file were accessible in the console browser. Now when I have started to work with different modules (files), top-level variables inside files aren't accessible from the console anymore. I guess the console represents a global scope (the window), but I'm not sure which are the variables visible now from the console interface?

Comment: By "console", you refer to the devtools REPL, not the `console` object, right?

Comment: By placing a breakpoint in the respective scope, all variables there should become accessible.

Comment: @Bergi, yes i'm talking about the console interface. Where to place a breakpoint? I'm talking on a code outside the modules

Comment: In code outside of the module, you will have to `import` the module to access it. But what I was referring to is to set a breakpoint in the module code itself, before it is loaded, and then when the execution halts on that breakpoint you can access all module-scoped variables from the console.

Comment: @Bergi, i will defiantly do this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, none of the variables in a module are accessible from the browser console.

You can expose a variable with this hack inside a module:

```js
let foo = { bar: 42 };
window.foo = foo;
```

Then:

```
> console.log(foo);
```

will display `{ bar: 42 }`.